# Solaris Non global Zone x server

Tags: solaris, x11

I am not even sure if this is possible but how can I start an X server on a non-global zone? If I run startx from within my zone. I created the xorg.conf by running /usr/X11/bin/xorgconfig

```
root@foo:/usr/X11/bin# startx
xauth:  creating new authority file /root/.serverauth.20957


X.Org X Server 1.5.3
Release Date: 5 November 2008
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: SunOS 5.11 snv_108 i86pc 
Current Operating System: SunOS dsol101 5.11 snv_111b i86pc
Build Date: 07 May 2009  04:44:56PM


Solaris ABI: 64-bit
SUNWxorg-server package version: 6.9.0.5.11.11100,REV=0.2009.05.07
SUNWxorg-mesa package version: 6.9.0.5.11.11100,REV=0.2009.04.02
        Before reporting problems, check http://sunsolve.sun.com/
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Nov 10 19:17:53 2009
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"

Fatal server error:
xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/fb (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 1):

An regular X server requires a display and input devices like a keyboard and a mouse. There are no such devices available on a non global zone and the ones available on the global zone, if any, are likely to be already used and are hardly shareable.

On the other hand, you can either launch a graphic environment on a NGZ with the X server being remote if your goal is to have a desktop running on that zone or you should be able to run one of the virtual X servers available like Xnest, Xvnc, Xvfb and perhaps Xephyr.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are not able to create the fb device in the zone like the follwing command(for example because you don't own the global zone) then you don't have a chance.

```
cp -a /devices/blah /zones/zone/devices/blah
```

Otherwise it might work, i get chrooted named working in a zone, but this might be more difficult issue. I come back to you if i find any solution.